# When I position an image to "fixed" it disappears? I want it to be positioned on top of another image within a div?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, fixed

HTML:  (The part I'm talking about is the very last div with the falling and cliff pngs. I'm wanting the falling png to appear only within that div and to be positioned on top of the cliff png. But it just disappears. I'm not sure what i'm doing lol

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/map_site00.css" />

<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 13px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #a3000d;
  background: black;
}


.bg img {
  width: 100%;
}


.bg {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.95;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("images/img_parallax.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("images/drought.jpg");
  min-height: 400px;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("images/story.jpg");
  min-height: 400px;
}

.bgimg-4 {
  background-image: url("images/missing1.gif");
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-5 {
  background-image: url("images/img_parallax.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-6 {
   background-image: url("images/smokeysays.jpg");
   min-height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

p {
  font: 25px "Lato", sans-serif;;

}

h1 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 35px "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    text-shadow:
   -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
     1px 1px 0 #000;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}


/* SOLVES IMAGE SIZE PROBLEM in POPUPS */

/*Use !important to Override any other CSS rules that may be affecting an element..."A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document"*/
.leaflet-popup-content {
    width:auto !important;
}

/*A tooltip is often used to specify extra information about something when the user moves the mouse pointer over an element*/



.leaflet-popup-tip {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }*/

/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .bg {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}



</style>

</head>
<body>

<div style="color: #fff;background-image:url(images/smoke.gif);text-align:center;padding:0px 0px; height: 100%; width: auto; text-align: justify; margin-top:-45px">
<center><p style="color: #aa0000;  text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 3.5em;  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    text-shadow:
   -.5px -.5px 0 #000,  
    .5px -.5px 0 #000,
    -.5px .5px 0 #000,
     .5px .5px 0 #000;">Story from the Ashes</p></center>
  <center><p style="color: #fff;  text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 2.0em;   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    text-shadow:
  -.5px -.5px 0 #000,  
    .5px -.5px 0 #000,
    -.5px .5px 0 #000,
     .5px .5px 0 #000;">Three years ago a strange series of disappearances from Western North Carolina occurred promoting surrounding authorities to search the area for the missing individuals. The disappearances took place over a period of about 6 months and beginning with a young women who went missing during a hiking trip with her best friend in Nantahala National Forest. </p></center>
  <center><img src="images/arrow.png"></img></center>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-4 bg">
  <div class="caption">
      <h1 style="text-align:center;">Images found on missing woman's social media hours before dissapearance along side a news segment</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>



<div class="bgimg-3 bg" style="height: 100%; position: relative">
<img src="images/falling.png" style=" z-index:2; height: 150px; width: 150px; left: 65%; position: fixed"></img>
    <img src="images/cliff.png" style="height: 70%; width: 50%; margin-top: 26%; margin-left: 50%"></img>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide an fiddle it would be really great BUT there are something that you should now. 
For start it would be better if you don't use `<center>` tag anymore it's departed on HTML5. Use CSS instead. 
And the second thing and probably your question, when you use `position: fixed;` the CSS fix the element from top left of the screen based on the attribute such as top and left that you gave it. So be careful and if you want to use it inside a div it's better if you use position `relative` or `absolute` .